# EWS recurring exception with removed attachemnt

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We use EWS to get meetings from Exchange and we faced with an issue connected with recurring exceptions. Scenario: we have recurrent meeting with attachments (attachments are attached to series, belong to master meeting). We change two occurrences: in first one we change subject, in second one we remove attachments. When we are trying to synchronize these meetings EWS get both of exception without attachments. First one should take attachments from master second one should not. However, we cannot find any difference between these two exceptions. How can we determine that in some exception attachment(s) was (were) removed?

Comment: I checked with the EWS editor (https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/), and I cant find a way to detect this. it looks like Exceptions, by default (in the calendar view) return no data on the attachments, while occurrences do. if I open the item By ID, the attachments (or the lack thereof) do show up, so it almost feels like the default item filter for exceptions ignores attachments...

Comment: when we load appointments, we include Attachments into PropertySet, I've also tryed to load Attachments property directly using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Bind method, but it didn't help.